# Is Instant Rails dead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, portable-applications

The last updated download on RubyForge (http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=904) is dated 2007-12-28. In Rails terms that is sometime in the last millenium. Is this project dead, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is bitnam (http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack)
it seems to be a valid alternative to the dead instantrails